# Wrong entry_date

Tags: entry-date

I just make new entries (19 may 2014) and on my site I get for entry_date 05 may 2014. I use plain EE tag:

```
{entry_date format="%m %F %Y"}
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Francois

Answer (score 4):

In your entry_date tag you're using ([date formatting docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html)):

```
%m (month)
%F (month, textual, 3 letters)
%Y (year, 4 digits)
```

So it's outputting as you've entered it. If you want 19 may 2014, change %m to %d like:

```
{entry_date format="%d %F %Y"}
```

Comment: Thanks Romans, I was not looking with my eyes or I'm getting to old.